# OSname equals Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard but AdfsVersion equals 2.0. How can this be? What to do?

Tags: windows

Excerpted results from PowerShell query:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-AdfsSystemInformation
OSVersion                 : 6.2.9200.0
OSName                    : Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
MachineType               : VMware Virtual Platform
AdfsVersion               : 2.0
```

I have read several places that AD FS 3.0 conforms to this statement: "the file "C:\Windows\ADFS\FSConfig.exe" DOES NOT exist (but the folder "C:\Windows\ADFS" does)". This is true for my server.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> [environment]::OSVersion.Version
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
6      2      9200   0
```

Looking up your reference, Ramhound, the above command doesn't differentiate between 2012 and 2012 R2, despite what some Microsoft documentation says.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> (Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption
Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am confused and don't know what to do.

Windows Server 2012 R2 only supports `Active Directory Federation Services 3.0`, it does not support, `Active Directory Federation Services 2.0`

> [image]

[Source](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=10909)

[Get-AdfsSystemInformation](https://github.com/Microsoft/adfsManagementTools/blob/master/diagnosticsModule/ADFSDiagnostics/Public/Get-AdfsSystemInformation.ps1) is part of the open source [ADFS Management Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=10909) project and it has a minor programming bug.  [Get-AdfsSystemInformation](https://github.com/Microsoft/adfsManagementTools/blob/master/diagnosticsModule/ADFSDiagnostics/Public/Get-AdfsSystemInformation.ps1) calls [Get-AdfsVersionEx](https://github.com/Microsoft/adfsManagementTools/blob/master/diagnosticsModule/ADFSDiagnostics/Public/Get-AdfsVersionEx.ps1) which uses the $OSVersion to determine if it will return a 2 or a 3 depending on the detected operating system version.  Since [Get-AdfsVersionEx](https://github.com/Microsoft/adfsManagementTools/blob/master/diagnosticsModule/ADFSDiagnostics/Public/Get-AdfsVersionEx.ps1) uses `[Environment]::OSVersion.Version` to determine the version of the operating system, instead of the correct method, it returns an incorrect value of *6.2.9200.0*.

This means that due to the following code the code is returning a value of 2 instead of 3.

```
If ($OSVersion.Major -eq 6)
    {
        # Windows 2012 R2
        If ($OSVersion.Minor -ge 3)
        {
            return $adfs3;
        }
```

> Any suggestions?

You can either fix the code yourself or report the [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/adfsManagementTools/issues) to Microsoft via the associated GitHub project.  In my research, it seems that AD FS on Windows Server 2012 R2, is simply `AD FS Windows Server 2012 R2` not ADFS 3.0.  Likewise, AD FS on Windows Server 2016 is `ADFS Windows Server 2016`.

I also noticed that the entire `Get-AdfsVersionEx` function is flawed, since the current version of ADFS, isn't actually 3.0 according to my research. So return the value for Windows 10/Server 2016 is actually currently incorrect.  The return value for `Windows Server 2012` would also be incorrect.

`Windows Server 2012`, `Windows Server 2012 R2`, and `Windows Server 2016` all are running on different versions of Active Directory Federation Services, but only support their specific version.  Migration to the next version is possible and is well documented (involves migration of the OS to the relevant OS), but otherwise not possible.

> I think you are saying that the AD FS version is reported incorrectly
>   by Get-AdfsSystemInformation, which you correctly revealed is part of
>   an open source diagnostic tool, available here. But, Get-AdfsVersionEx
>   returns 2.0, which supports the tool's assessment.

I am indeed saying that.  The reason the module isn't working, is due to the fact, `[Environment]::OSVersion.Version` returns the same value for both `Windows Server 2012` and `Windows Server 2012 R2`.

> The OSVersion property reports the same version number (6.2.0.0) for
>   both Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 and the same major and minor version
>   number for Windows 10.

Source: [Environment.OSVersion Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> This document contradicts that: MS Docs. The OSName should be reported
>   as Windows Server 2012. Therefore the OSName, as reported, is false,
>   and the ADFS version is correct.

I based my entire answer on the information you provided.  The information you provided indicated the build was *6.2.9200.0* instead of the correct value.

> ```
> PS C:\Windows\system32> [environment]::OSVersion.Version
> Major  Minor  Build  Revision
> -----  -----  -----  --------
> 6      2      9200   0
> ```

Even though you are running Windows Server 2012 R2, the version that is reported is causing the module to report the incorrect version of `Active Directory Federation Services`.  **You're by the way server is running `Active Directory Federation Services` 3.0**

Comment: The bottom line is the fact the module you are using, has a huge programming error in it, but there are solutions to fix it yourself.  [How to find the Windows version from the PowerShell command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330187/how-to-find-the-windows-version-from-the-powershell-command-line).

Comment: @David Your question wasn’t that though, your question was why the command you were using, was returning 2 instead of 3.  While I am perfectly capable of suggesting a solution myself, I won’t be fixing the module, because honestly the module could be rewritten to a simple return statement.